# Make the display 8 bit and set palette

Tags: pygame, display, surface, palette

I have an 8-bit colour depth surface and some 8-bit colours, and I set the surface up like this:

```
self.surf = pygame.Surface((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)).convert(8)
self.surf.set_palette(self.colours)
```

I tried to make the display 8-bit so I wouldn't have to blit the surface to it as I wondered if I could just set the pixels on the display screen directly.  First I tried:

`screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size = (SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT), depth = 8)`

and

`pygame.display.set_palette(self.colours)`

But it said:

```
pygame.error: Display mode is not colormapped
```

So I tried:

```
self.surf = pygame.display.get_surface().convert(8)
self.surf.set_palette(self.colours)
```

and:

```
self.surf.set_at((i, index), the_colour)
```

But nothing seems to work.  Is there a way to address the display directly similar to how you can with a surface and set_at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a backwards compatibility bug in pygame 2. https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/991.

You could get around this by downgrading to pygame 1.9.6, but I would recommend staying on pygame 2 to take advantage of all the new features.

Comment: Interestingly, if I do: `screen_surf = pygame.display.get_surface().convert(8)
   print('get depth = {}'.format(screen_surf.get_bitsize()))` it shows bit depth as 8!